Flutter Login Layout Rendering
I'm facing an issue on rendering the login layout page. In some devices (iPhone, Android, pc) the page shows all the texts, in other no. To what could be due this behavior?
I attached what I see in my Android phone click here
Thanks,
Giuliana
I try to open the app in the incognito mode, but without success. I would like to know if it is a issue of flutter or of the device settings/version.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
